# easyautocomplete how to getValue key of json

Tags: json

i have a json like this:

```
{ 
"typeA": { "option1": "one", "option2": "two" } ,
"typeB": { "option1": "one", "option2": "two" } ,
"typeC": { "option1": "one", " option2": "two" } 
}
```

i use http://easyautocomplete.com/.

My question is: how to select key in getValue for match 'TypeA, or TypeB or Type C'

```
getValue: function(element) {

     return Object.keys(element);

}
```

Comment: You're trying to access the `"typeA"` from the object content of `typeA`, or get the object content of `typeA` from the string `typeA` ?

Comment: i want match type a from the string